# "self" when we use it in a time zone method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am reading the online help guide and it says:

> utc_to_local(time) Link Adjust the given time to the simultaneous time
>   in the time zone represented by self. Returns a Time.utc() instance –
>   if you want an ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone instance, use
>   Time#in_time_zone instead.

I know `self` is like "this" that we have in C# , but not sure how does it apply to Rails and web-apps? ? So does it mean it will look at the browser and browser will look at time zone of the client computer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`self` is the timezone you called this method on.

For example: `ActiveSupport::TimeZone.find_tzinfo("America/New_York").utc_to_local(time)`

It has nothing to do with the browser, it's server-side.

Comment: thanks. So from my understanding Rails saves to DB by "UTC" format. So when users see it on their browsers how can we make sure they see the Local time version of that UTC time? This isn't the right method to use for this purpose?

Comment: You can't really know the timezone of your users, unless you ask them to set it, or have their location. Look for "rails set user timezone" in google. The basic idea is to set Time.zone to the user timezone for every request.

Answer (score 2):

`self` is `this`, the current object. In this context, `self` is a instance of `ActiveSupport::TimeZone`, which has the data for the time zone it represents. This concept is orthogonal to Rails and web-apps, and the browser.

This method calls TZInfo's `utc_to_local` method, which is documented as:

> Converts a time in UTC to the local timezone. utc can either be a DateTime, Time or timestamp (Time.to_i). The returned time has the same type as utc. Any timezone information in utc is ignored (it is treated as a UTC time).

http://tzinfo.rubyforge.org/doc/